# How to get daylight saving time boundaries for the past 10 years

Tags: c#, .net, windows

How can I get daylight saving time boundaries for every single time zone using C#?

Comment: You can start with this Wikipedia article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time_by_region_and_country

Answer (score 5):

<strike>Take a look at the [TimeZone.GetDaylightChanges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezone.getdaylightchanges.aspx) method.</strike>

EDIT:

Looking at the TimeZone class, it seems like it will only support the local time zone, and only the current year. Take a look at[TimeZoneInfo.GetAdjustmentRules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.getadjustmentrules.aspx), which will let you get the adjustment rules for arbitrary time zones. The example on that page even seems pretty similar to your task here.

Comment: Would this take into account the change to the date that was made a few years go?

Comment: "The TimeZone class supports only a single daylight saving time adjustment rule for the local time zone." - so no historical changes. Also, it's a pain to get time zones other than the local one.

Comment: @aserwin It ought to, although if you mean what happens if you try to get the date for previous years, I think that that will not work based on the notes on the page. Actually, it looks like TimeZone can only be the time zone of the local system, so I may need to edit my answer to reflect that. TimeZoneInfo.GetAdjustmentRules may be the better way here.

Comment: @JakeP: No, it's documented *not* to take account of changes to daylight saving transitions. `TimeZoneInfo.GetAdjustmentRules` will work, but it's a pain to use.

Comment: @Jon Skeet I took that to mean that the daylight transition for the current year would be correct, but previous year data would match whatever the of the current year returns.

Comment: @JakeP: Yes, exactly - which I doubt is what the OP wants, given the title.

Comment: @Jon Skeet You are right! I missed the title, only read the question.

Answer (score 4):

Disclaimer: I'm the main author of the Noda Time library referenced below :)

It's *relatively* tricky using just the vanilla .NET code:

- `TimeZone` doesn't use historical data
- `TimeZoneInfo` doesn't make it easy to find transitions; you have to interpret the rule data yourself, basically. [`TimeZoneInfo.GetAdjustmentRules`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.getadjustmentrules.aspx) *does* give you all the information, but from experience I'd advise you to avoid trying to code against it unless you really have to.

Using [Noda Time](http://noda-time.googlecode.com) you can do this fairly easily, however. The code below uses the wrappers around the BCL time zones; change `Bcl` to `Tzdb` to use the TZDB time zones ("Europe/London" etc).

```
using System;
using NodaTime;

class Test
{
    static readonly Instant Start = Instant.FromUtc(2002, 10, 17, 0, 0);
    static readonly Instant End = Instant.FromUtc(2012, 10, 17, 0, 0);

    static void Main()
    {
        var provider = DateTimeZoneProviders.Bcl;
        foreach (var id in provider.Ids)
        {
            var zone = provider[id];
            ShowTransitions(zone);
        }        
    }

    static void ShowTransitions(DateTimeZone zone)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}:", zone.Id);
        var zoneInterval = zone.GetZoneInterval(Start);
        while (zoneInterval.End < End)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}: {2}",
                              zoneInterval.Start,
                              zoneInterval.End,
                              zoneInterval.WallOffset);
            zoneInterval = zone.GetZoneInterval(zoneInterval.End);
        }
    }
}
```